# OSX: free software that can assign commands to modifier key + mouse button actions

Tags: osx, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there free software for osx that can assign commands to modifier key+ mouse button actions? For example, I'd like to emulate pressing F1 when I clicked the right button on my mouse while holding down the option key; not keyboard keys alone or mouse buttons alone.

Comment: Is it OK to use two programs to do this? Does it have to be free? That makes it harder.

Comment: Better Touch Tool is able to do this. It is however, not free anymore. But it uses the pay-what-you-want-model, so it isn't too expensive. It's quite helpfull in many ways.